# How do I sort multiple dynamic queues without STL in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, queue

I just started learning about stacks, queues, and decks. From what I've seen so far from my textbooks and from the internet, I've grasped the way a queue works. I'm trying to solve a problem that I got as homework so I'm not asking for the entire solution, I just want a piece of advice on how to go about said problem.

What I'm trying to do is to take 2 dynamic queues and sort them by the size of the elements and then pop said elements into a third queue that also is going to get sorted. The easiest way for me would've been to pop all of the elements into an array to sort them and then to push them into the queue, however part of the task was to not use any extra space.

I've thought of ways to do that and here's what I came up with: each queue will get sorted separately by popping 2 of its elements, then comparing them, and pushing the smaller one back in while keeping the bigger one to compare it to the next element of the queue. By the n-th rotation, they should've gotten sorted.

What confuses me is how to do the function that is going to compare them. I've tried to write the code but can't do a lot since we are not permitted to use `stl` libraries.  I know that the question is pretty dumb but I've spent all week looking this up and I have no idea what to do anymore. Even if it's a link to a site that explains how this should work I'd still appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct elem {
    int key;
    elem* next;
}* first = NULL, * last = NULL;

struct elem2 {
    int key2;
    elem2* next3;
}* first2 = NULL, * last2 = NULL;

struct elem3 {
    int key3;
    elem3* next3;
}* first3 = NULL, * last3 = NULL;

//elem *push(int n, elem *&first, elem *&last);
//elem *pop(int &n, elem *&first, elem *&last);

elem* push(int n, elem*& first, elem*& last)
{
    elem* p = last;
    last = new elem;
    last->key = n;
    last->next = NULL;
    if (p != NULL)
        p->next = last;
    else
        first = last;
    return p;
}

elem* pop(int& n, elem*& first, elem*& last)
{
    elem* p = NULL;
    if (first) {
        n = first->key;
        p = first;
        first = first->next;
        ;

        if (first == NULL)
            last = first;

        return p;
        delete p;
    }
    else
        return nullptr;
}

void main()
{
    int ch, num, amount, i = 1;
    do {
        cout << "\n\t Menu";
        cout << "\n 1.Add elements";
        cout << "\n 2.Add elements to second queue";
        cout << "\n 3. Merge queues and sort them";
        cout << "\n 4.Exit";
        do {
            cout << "\n Your choice is:";
            cin >> ch;
        } while (ch < 1 || ch > 4);
        switch (ch)

        {
        case 1:
            cout << "How many elements would you like to add? \n";
            cin >> amount;
            cout << "Input queue elements:\n";

            for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                cin >> num;
                elem* push(int num, elem*& first, elem*& last);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "How many elements would you like to add? \n";
            cin >> amount;
            cout << "Input queue elements:\n";

            for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                cin >> num;
                elem2* push(int num, elem2*& first2, elem2*& last2);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            break;
        }
    } while (ch != 4);
}
```

I've fixed most of it so far. The only thing I still struggle to do is to sort them into the third queue. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: this `elem* push(int num, elem*& first, elem*& last);` is a declaration of function not a function call. So it does nothing in those `for` loops. Please master basic before trying to solve more complex tasks (like this one). There is more mistake like this so there is not point to trying to fix your code.

Comment: *I've thought of ways to do that and here's what I came up with:* -- You've just described the merge portion of a merge sort.

Comment: Problems is mastering basics of language not the task it self, so question should be closed (SO doesn't have proper option to close this one).

Comment: However doesn't it require to have #include <queue> in order for it to work? One of the things I have to do is to not use any stl libraries

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question was that you want to implement the merge function of merge sort for queues without using any extra space. I have written some code; consider going through this. Feel free to comment if you want more clarification...

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Ref.: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-linked-list-implementation/

struct QNode {
    int data;
    QNode *next;
    QNode(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

struct Queue {
    QNode *front, *rear;

    int size;

    Queue() {
        front = rear = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    void enQueue(int x) {
        QNode *temp = new QNode(x);
        if (rear == NULL) {
            front = rear = temp;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        rear->next = temp;
        rear = temp;
        size++;
    }

    void deQueue() {
        if (front == NULL)
            return;
        QNode *temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        if (front == NULL)
            rear = NULL;
        delete (temp);
        size--;
    }

    void display() {
        if (front == NULL) {
            cout << "The queue is empty!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        QNode *temp = front;
        while (temp) {
            cout << temp->data << " --> ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int at(int i) { // gets q[i]
        if (i < 0 or i >= size)
            throw out_of_range("The index is not valid!");
        QNode *temp = front;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            temp = temp->next;
        return temp->data;
    };

    void replace_at(int x, int i) { // sets q[i] = x
        if (i < 0 or i >= size)
            throw out_of_range("The index is not valid!");
        QNode *temp = front;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->data = x;
    }
};

// Ref.: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays-o1-extra-space/

void merge(Queue q1, Queue q2) {
    int m = q1.size;
    int n = q2.size;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int j, last = q1.at(m - 1);
        for (j = m - 2; j >= 0 and q1.at(j) > q2.at(i); j--)
            q1.replace_at(q1.at(j), j + 1);
        if (j != m - 2 || last > q2.at(i)) {
            q1.replace_at(q2.at(i), j + 1);
            q2.replace_at(last, i);
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    Queue q1, q2;
    char ch;
    int data;
    do {
        cout << endl
             << "MENU" << endl
             << "1.\t Add elements to queue 1" << endl
             << "2.\t Add elements to queue 2" << endl
             << "3.\t Merge and sort the two queues" << endl
             << "4.\t Exit" << endl
             << endl
             << "Enter your choice : ";
    lb:
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch) {
            case '1':
                cout << "Enter the data you want to insert : ";
                cin >> data;
                q1.enQueue(data);
                cout << "Queue after this operation : ";
                q1.display();
                break;
            case '2':
                cout << "Enter the data you want to insert : ";
                cin >> data;
                q2.enQueue(data);
                cout << "Queue after this operation : ";
                q2.display();
                break;
            case '3':
                merge(q1, q2);
                cout << "Queue 1 after this operation : ";
                q1.display();
                cout << "Queue 2 after this operation : ";
                q2.display();
                break;
            case '4':
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Please check your choice!" << endl
                     << "Re-enter your choice : ";
                goto lb;
        }
    } while (ch != '4');

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample run :

```
> solution.exe

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 1
Enter the data you want to insert : 1
Queue after this operation : 1 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 1
Enter the data you want to insert : 5
Queue after this operation : 1 --> 5 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 1
Enter the data you want to insert : 9
Queue after this operation : 1 --> 5 --> 9 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 1
Enter the data you want to insert : 10
Queue after this operation : 1 --> 5 --> 9 --> 10 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 1
Enter the data you want to insert : 15
Queue after this operation : 1 --> 5 --> 9 --> 10 --> 15 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 1
Enter the data you want to insert : 20
Queue after this operation : 1 --> 5 --> 9 --> 10 --> 15 --> 20 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 2
Enter the data you want to insert : 2
Queue after this operation : 2 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 2
Enter the data you want to insert : 3
Queue after this operation : 2 --> 3 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 2
Enter the data you want to insert : 8
Queue after this operation : 2 --> 3 --> 8 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 2
Enter the data you want to insert : 13
Queue after this operation : 2 --> 3 --> 8 --> 13 --> 

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 3
Queue 1 after this operation : 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 5 --> 8 --> 9 -->
Queue 2 after this operation : 10 --> 13 --> 15 --> 20 -->

MENU
1.       Add elements to queue 1
2.       Add elements to queue 2
3.       Merge and sort the two queues
4.       Exit

Enter your choice : 4
```